# Fully MS-compatible office

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice 3.4.5 on CentOS. Unfortunately, it's not fully compatible with MS Office. In particular, reading docx files leads to loosing all of the embedded formulae and some of the drawings. This makes it necessary for me to switch back and forth between MacBook running MS Office and CentOS workstation where I do development.

Thus the question: could you recommend fully MS-compatible office with equivalents of Word, Excel, and PowerPoint? Something which would not drop the math formulae and wouldn't rotate drawn objects differently from MS apps?

Comment: Which version of CentOS are you running? there is a much newer version of libreoffice that should provide better compatibility but it might not be available for old versions of CentOS.

Comment: @zer0rest: updated LibreOffice to 4.4.2, same problem. CentOS release 6.3.

Comment: Your best bet is probably installing Office under Wine or on a Windows virtual machine.

Comment: If you really need "Office" and it's limitations I mean features, you should just run Windows and buy Office. It's honestly not worth asking for complete compatibility with software as complex and as unspecified as Word and Excel and Powerpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source [**ONLYOFFICE Desktop**](https://www.onlyoffice.com/apps.aspx) for Linux, which [claims to have the best compliance](https://help.onlyoffice.com/products/files/doceditor.aspx?fileid=5046061&doc=MTN0MThmUjJTRmhHNWVMS0UwUmFvdEVzWFBCSDZZaXJzQUlGWlJzdS95OD0_IjUwNDYwNjEi0) with Microsoft Office among free editors. Give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

The only product that is fully compatible with Microsoft Office from a file transfer perspective is the same version of Microsoft Office itself. (Even different versions of Microsoft Office are known to have compatibility variations.)

The obvious contenders are [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) and [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), with possible support from the likes of Abiword, but these are inherently not 100% perfectly compatible.

Have you tried a more recent version of LibreOffice? Its website shows that [version 4.4.3 is available](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) (4.4.2 if you want the stable released version). That is a marked increase from the version 3.4.5 you say you are currently running.

Comment: Just installed LibreOffice 4.4.2. Unfortunately handling of math formulae is as horrible as in earlier versions. Basically, the formula entries are replaced with placeholders, similar to viewing a document with unsupported character set.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to install the OS you're ordinarily using for Office in a virtual machine running on top of your CentOS box, and use MS Office there.